# [python-selenium 4.3.0]How to get element by text under tag a?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i would like to get the element and click on it by the text under tag a:

`<a href="https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=29433">1791</a>` 
The text "1791" is what I used to locate this element and click on it.

My code looks like this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,("//div[text()='1791']")).click()
```

and it does not work. My selenium version is 4.3.0, so it does not support command such as find_element_by_xpath. Hence, the answers I found on the internet offers no help.

Thank you!

Comment: `driver.find_element(By.XPATH,("//a[text()='1791']")).click()` there is no `<div>` but a `<a>` tag

Comment: it does not work. it gave me "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[text()='1791']"}"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to click on the **div** with the text '1791'.
But in the provided info this text is inside **a** tag.

Try the following:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,("//a[text()='1791']")).click()
```

#### UPD

Except for the incorrect XPath the problem was in unused [WebDriverWait](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) for the element (the expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page before clicking on it).

Webdriver tries to click an element immediately after opening the desired page, but some elements may not be loaded yet.

The final code will be:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,("//a[text()='1791']"))).click()
```

With imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: it does not work. it gave me "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[text()='1791']"}"

Comment: @ArrenZhou could you provide the full DOM?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know how to provide DOM on this. But I was trying to scrape 

https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/documents/presidential-documents-archive-guidebook/annual-messages-congress-the-state-the-union

by starting from George Washington 1791. I hope this will give you enough information. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry it's still not working. It gave: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td//a[text()='1971']"}.

Comment: @ArrenZhou I think that you are not using any wait conditions and driver is trying to click on the element that was not downloaded yet.

You should add something like this:
`WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,("//a[text()='1791']"))).click()`

And don't forget about the proper imports:

`from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`

Comment: OMG It worked. Thank you so much!!!! You have no obligation to do that but you chose to help me out. It is people who are like you that make the internet a wonderful place. I really thank you!

Comment: @ArrenZhou could you please mark the updated answer as proper to help to find the solution to the same problem for other people?